# How to create paramater(mutabledictionary) which inclued mutablearray in dictionary in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have paramaters which needed to be passed in POST type.

**The paramaters are**

```
{
    "couponamt": 0,
    "pincode": 110093,
    "proinfo": 
        [
          { "prodPrice": 2289,
            "prodSize": "",
            "proid": 41211,
            "promapid": 68804,
            "proname": "Spigen SGP10905 Gunmetal  iPhone 6 (5.5inch) Case ",
            "qty": 1,
            "vendorId": 1050
          }, 
          {  "prodPrice": 6422,
             "prodSize": "3X8 Feet",
             "proid": 61554,
             "promapid": 110886,
             "proname": "Kaka Carpet K00108 Camel Tibbati Gabbeh Carpet",
             "qty": 1,
             "vendorId": 1066
         }, 
         {   "prodPrice": 3996,
             "prodSize": "XL",
             "proid": 99003,
             "promapid": 162976,
             "proname": "AbsurdABWS15-625GreyWomenSweatshirt",
             "qty": 4,"vendorId": 885
        }
     ],
   "shipcharge": 75,
   "totalAmount": 1599,
   "usedwalletamount": 0
}
```

I want to pass this paramter with my url to create request.And it is in the form of array.Kindly revert ASAP.
Thanks

Comment: Can You Provide Some more detail?

Comment: Listed above is the paramater,i just want to make request via creating this as a parmater

Comment: get JSONStringFromDictionary and set that as value or whatever parameter key your server is expecting

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, create `NSMutableDictionary` with 7 keys namely prodPrice, prodSize,  proid, promapid, proname, qty, vendorId.
Set desired values for your `keys`. 
After this, create `NSMutableArray` and add all your dictionaries to this array.

Now create 1 final `NSMutableDictionary` which will be used as value for whatever parameter key your server is expecting.
In this dictionary, set your above created `NSMutableArray` as value for key proinfo. Similarly set values for other keys couponamt, pincode, shipcharge etc.
Finally append this dictionary with your base url.

Answer (score 0):

So as far I get the original question we need to create the below structure:

```
 - NSMutableDictionary
    -NSMutableArray 
       -NSDictionary
 - NSDictionary
```

You simply need to create the `NSMutableArray` and `NSDictionary` object.
Based on your requirement you can add dictionary on respective indexes in `NSMutableArray`, which can be collectively added in the `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: you don't need to do anything fancy..Here is code snippet from stackoverflow itself
`AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];`